# split the number given by user so RHS= LHS

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

split the number where RHS multiplication is equal to LHS input by the user.

if there is no split available return -1
if multiple return least split

input

```
142811
```

output

```
1*4*2 =8*1*1
>>>3
```

input

```
301501
```

output

```
3*0=1*5*0*1 
>>>2
```

i could just convert the number to the list

```
a=int(input("enter a number="))
res = [int(x) for x in str(a)]
```

and after that i could not know possible algorithm for it

Comment: Two things for you to ponder are: 1. How many split points are there? (say in the examples you give) 2. If you already knew the split point, how would you write code to check it was right?

Comment: we have to search for a split point through code , where rhs =Lhs

Comment: I understand the question, but you say that you don't know how to go about writing an algorithm. I was giving you some points to ponder on while you make an attempt to solve this.

Comment: can you provide me the solution ? i tried everything and still trying but getting no where. it will be helpful if u give me solution so i understand quickly , actually im just 17 and im learning python rn so please help me

Comment: Sorry, no, you first. Please update your question with one of your attempts. Stackoverflow is not your personal development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
# Your code to get the number in a list
a=int(input("enter a number="))
res = [int(x) for x in str(a)]

# Define function to get the product of a list of numbers
def product(nums):
    ret = 1
    for n in nums:
        ret *= n
    return ret

# Iterate through numbers
for i in range(len(res)):
    # Check if the products match
    if product(res[:i]) == product(res[i:]):
        # If they do, output and break
        print('*'.join(str(x) for x in res[:i]), '=', '*'.join(str(y) for y in res[i:]))
        break
else:
    # If no break occurred, output 'Not found.'
    print('Not found.')
```

Output:

```py
enter a number=142811
1*4*2 = 8*1*1
```

Comment: `res = [int(x) for x in input("enter a number: ")]` - why detour via `a`/ an int?

Comment: @greybeard - that's not my code. OP put that in the question so I used it.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
def code(a):
    cnt = 1
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        list_lhs = a[:i]
        list_rhs = a[i:]
        
        left,right = 1,1
        
        for n in list_lhs:
            left = left*int(n)
        for n in list_rhs:
            right = right*int(n)
        if left == right:
            cnt = 0
            print("Found Split at",i,":",list_lhs, "and", list_rhs)
            break
    if cnt == 1:
        print("-1")
code(a = "301501")

# Found Split at 2 : 30 and 1501
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from math import prod


def base10list(n: int) -> list[int]:
    return [int(s) for s in str(n)]


def split_mul(n: int) -> int:
    numbers = base10list(n)
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if prod(numbers[:i]) == prod(numbers[i:]):
            return i
    return -1


def main() -> None:
    a = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    print("Split index:", split_mul(a))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
enter an integer: 142811
Split index: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like try this:

```
def get_split(usr_input_str):
    lst_digits = [digit for digit in usr_input_str]
    for i in range(1,len(lst_digits)):
        str_expr = '*'.join(lst_digits[0:i])+'=='+'*'.join(lst_digits[i:])
        if eval(str_expr):
            print(str_expr)
            return 
    print(-1)
get_split("142811")
```

Here how it works:

- `for i in range(1,len(lst_digits)-1):` start with a split position after the first digit (therefore the 1, in range) and check all positions until the last digit (therefore `,len(lst_digits)`)
- build a string inserting "==" at the split position `i` and "*" in all other positions (done by  `str_expr =`)
- check if the string (fo example `"1*4*2==8*1*1"` evaluates to `True` and print the string if it does
- if the loop over all split positions did not print anything print(`-1`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
#multiply elements of list
def mul(nl):
  product = 1
  for n in nl:
    product = product*n
  return product


def calculate_split_point(numList):
  for i in range(1, len(numList)):
    if mul(numList[:i]) == mul(numList[i:]):
      numList = [str(n) for n in numList]
      print(f'{"*".join(numList[:i])} = {"*".join(numList[i:])}')
      return i
  
  return -1


num = input("Enter a number :: ")
numList = [int(n) for n in num]   # List of numbers

calculate_split_point(numList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting and unique problem, loved solving it!

```
def multiply(num):
   total = 1
   for n in num: total*=int(n)
   return total
def equ(num, split):
    t1 = multiply(num[:split])
    t2 = multiply(num[-(len(num)-split):])
    ret_value = split if split <= len(num)-split else len(num) - split
    if t2 == t1: return ret_value
    else: return False

inp = input("Enter a number:")
p_splits = len(inp) - 1
splits = []
for i in range(p_splits):
    val = equ(inp, i+1)
    if not val == False:
        splits.append(val)
splits.sort()
try: print(splits[0])
except IndexError: print("-1")
```